# Java web start without X

Tags: java, jar, java-web-start

I need to start my application in different Linux servers using SSH. I thought to use java web start so I can pack my application once and run it on the servers by dynamically downloading the application. The big problem is that the server does not have X started and when I launch the command

> javaws -Xnosplash

the application returns immediately with no output.

Is there a way to get the stdout/stderr of the application to understand what is going wrong?

Edit: Sorry the description is incomplete. The application does not use a GUI, it is supposed to run as a command line application. I need JWS because I can use different launch files with an high number of parameters for testing purposes, and I can deploy the application once, and run it on multiple servers.

Now when I run it using the java command everything works fine, with javaws the commands returns quietly and I do not know what is going wrong.

p.s. I cannot see any logs under /.java/* directory

Comment: Could you just run it with just java <class files> to get stdout? [Source](http://lopica.sourceforge.net/faq.html#trace-parsing)

Comment: With _java_ everything works fine, with _javaws_ I have no output whatsoever

Answer (score 1):

we run several applications that needs a display to run correctly

On Linux, we're using [xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb) with great success.

I don't think AWT/Swing classes can initialize themselves without display/framebuffer

Comment: +1 for xvfb. That's how I've gotten Swing apps (and anything doing graphic processing) running on Unix on the background. Indeed AWT/Swing cannot initialize itself without a display/framebuffer.

Comment: Probably won't work, because Web Start will ask the user if the web start app should be allowed to run, and it will wait forever for a click which will not come.

Comment: @Robin Green   Then he can use xdotool, or another virtual input device, and click on it :-D

Comment: thank you but I don't need to simulate X but I just need to know why my app is not running (p.s. I didn't know xvfb, thanks)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get the stdout/stderr of the application to understand what is going wrong?

On Linux, Java Web Start (by default) puts trace files in

```
~/.java/deployment/log/
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/tracing_logging.html

Comment: That still doesn't tell him how to initialize a Swing/AWT app running as a background process on a \*nix machine without X running on it ;)

Comment: @luis you are obviously correct; I was only answering the "Is there a way to get the stdout/stderr of the application to understand what is going wrong?" part.

Comment: Oh, mea culpa. I guess I didn't RTFA completely before replying back :P

Comment: No worries! I should have included the sub-question I was answering (fixed in my edit).

Comment: This is strange, I'm using the sun-java6-jdk and it does not put any logs under that directory (even though I tried to create the .javawsrc file)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use OpenJDK - it shares most of the code with the JDK, but it uses its own open source implementation of Java web start. If it doesn't already support this, you can probably modify it to run in a text-based way *fairly* easily.

Comment: "you can probably modify it to run in a text-based way *fairly* easily." - can you quantify what you mean by *fairly* easily? What you are suggesting is great and dandy if the person has the time and the technical wherewithal. Most lack the former as they typically have to get things running on schedule and while on payroll. A fellow named Occam might have something to say about this. As intellectually stimulating this exercise might be, the more appropriate thing is to simply use **xvfb**. Tried and true. Cost effective. Widely known. Better than modifying OpenJDK, don't you think?

Comment: Depends on the app. I've had JEE apps running on machines receiving http requests and computing graphs to be send back as output (relying on xvfb on the background). If the app is a graphic interface, then obviously, this won't work. But ignoring those, any app that requires to use graphics (be it for GUI or for generating graphics) requires an X server to be present.

Comment: And unless the app in question is in closed-form (no src), it is typically cheaper to modify an app to take serialized input of some form than to modify the underlying graphics platform (which was never intended to received serialized input to begin with.) Modifying the OpenJDK like this sounds like a solution to a problem. And this problem is about running an application in an environment (and way) it was not architect-ed for (not valid enough to spend time and effort mod'ing the jdk IMO.)